# Tab-Control inside normal Activity, is it possible?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost

I'm running into trouble when try to put an tabhost layout inside an normal layout.

The structure of my layout is:

```
<LinearLayout >
    <LinearLayout>
    ....
    </LinearLayout>
   <TabHost>
    .....
   </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

I try to draw this picture to help it easier to image about what I'm saying:

[image: How it looks !]

Can you give me a hint for this problem ? I will do the rest, no need a full solution, just a hint, please :)

Thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a little while since I dealt with Android, but if I recall TabHost is essentially a container that stores both the tabs and the viewport that the tabs switch between. TabHost extends from FrameLayout so you can use it as the root element in a layout. What I think you actually want is this:

```
<TabHost>
   <LinearLayout android:layout_orientation="vertical">
      <TextView />     // your title
      <View />         // content below your title but above your tabs
      <TabWidget />    // your tabs
      <FrameLayout />  // content controlled by your tabs
   </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: yes, you're correct ! we can do that way, but I find anther way to do this, much flexible and got the same effect, that is using buttons replace it, and loading layout in a seperated flow.
Whatever, thank for your answer :)